# Python 2.7.3 memory error

Tags: python

I have a specific case with python code. Every time I run the code, the RAM memory is increasing until it reaches 1.8 gb and crashes.

```
import itertools
import csv
import pokersleuth

cards = ['2s',  '3s',   '4s',   '5s',   '6s',   '7s',   '8s',   '9s',   'Ts',   'Js',   'Qs',   'Ks',   'As',   '2h',   '3h',   '4h',   '5h',   '6h',   '7h',   '8h',   '9h',   'Th',   'Jh',   'Qh',   'Kh',   'Ah',   '2c',   '3c',   '4c',   '5c',   '6c',   '7c',   '8c',   '9c',   'Tc',   'Jc',   'Qc',   'Kc',   'Ac',   '2d',   '3d',   '4d',   '5d',   '6d',   '7d',   '8d',   '9d',   'Td',   'Jd',   'Qd',   'Kd',   'Ad']
flop = itertools.combinations(cards,3)

a1 = 'Ks' ; a2 = 'Qs'
b1 = 'Jc' ; b2 = 'Jd'

cards1 = a1+a2
cards2 = b1+b2

number = 0
n=0
m=0

for row1 in flop:
    if (row1[0] <> a1 and row1[0] <>a2 and row1[0] <>b1 and row1[0] <>b2) and (row1[1] <> a1 and row1[1] <>a2 and row1[1] <>b1 and row1[1] <>b2) and (row1[2] <> a1 and row1[2] <> a2 and row1[2] <> b1 and row1[2] <> b2):
        for row2 in cards:
            if (row2 <> a1 and row2 <> a2 and row2 <> b1 and row2 <> b2 and row2 <> row1[0] and row2 <> row1[1] and row2 <> row1[2]):
                s = pokersleuth.compute_equity(row1[0]+row1[1]+row1[2]+row2, (cards1, cards2))
                if s[0]>=0.5:
                    number +=1
                    del s[:]
                del s[:]

        print number/45.0
        number = 0
        n+=1
```

Comment: what is the intent with `del s[:]`?  That's deleting a newly created copy of s.

Comment: Just tried to delete the list, since I where the data goes. I am not saving anything, just printing the result.

Comment: Holy cow, who wrote this spaghetti.  Also, what does `pokersleuth.compute_equity()` do?  You don't need to delete the list, btw...

Comment: @Benden Brown it empties the list. [Del docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement)

Comment: @sean Thanks, I've never seen that idiom before.

Comment: butterscotch.compute_equity() is the module that calculates the probability of winning in poker when you give board and players' cards. The code was fast written just to quickly test one thing.

Comment: I can't see an issue with your code as it is only dealing with a single combination at a time as the combinations are being generated from a generator. Hmm, nevermind showing that code here found the`pokesleuth` module.

Comment: http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=UkQRX here is the module code.

Answer (score 2):

My tests where the memory leak occurred were inconclusive, but under the assumption that it didn't happen in montecarlo.dll, I thought I'd try `multiprocessing.Pool()` and split the work in smaller chunks that I load off to some processes which I could terminate before they start using excessive memory:

```
from itertools import combinations, product, islice
from multiprocessing import Pool
from pokersleuth import compute_equity

num_procs = 4
num_jobs = 256
chunk_size = num_procs * num_jobs

join = ''.join

drawn = a1, a2, b1, b2 = 'Ks', 'Qs', 'Jc', 'Jd'
pairs = (a1 + a2, b1 + b2)

deck = (join(reversed(c)) for c in product('shcd', '23456789TJQKA'))
deck = [card for card in deck if card not in drawn]

def compute_chances(cards):
    return sum(compute_equity(cards + card, pairs)[0] >= 0.5
               for card in deck if card not in cards) / 45.0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    combis = (join(each) for each in combinations(deck, 3))
    i = 0
    while True:
        pool = Pool(processes=num_procs)
        chunk = list(islice(combis, chunk_size))
        for i, chances in enumerate(pool.imap(compute_chances, chunk), i + 1):
            print i, chances
        pool.terminate()
        if len(chunk) < chunk_size:
            break
```

The results are the same as in your program.

Here's what Task Manager says about memory consumption for the last 7 loops of 17 (17296 combinations with a `chunk_size` of 1024):

[image: 10 loops]

Each loop used about 400 MB and it took 34 miuntes to process all combinations.

Instead of manually typing in a whole deck of cards, I have the computer create it for me. I refuse to do things that a computer can do.

To keep the amount of data passed to each process as small as possible, I only send each combination of three cards to `compute_chances()` and have everything else computed there.

I'm not shure if montecarlo.dll is reentrant, but the results seem to indicate that it is.

The values of `num_procs` and `num_jobs` in my code worked well on my machine. You should play around with them to find optimal settings for yours.

Answer (score 1):

You're running on <strike>Linux (am I right?), and you're hitting the maximum process image size on your system, because processes on linux cannot reduce their memory size.</strike> windows.

Your options are to split this up so that it can resume after hitting the memory limit, compiling a kernel with a higher process size limit<strike>, or running on windows</strike>.

Comment: Good point, Marcin! However, I'm running it on Windows. Could the problem remain on this system as well?

Comment: @TomBaker In that case, it is likely either (a) a problem with the code you are using or (b) just a fact that your code needs a bunch of memory, because windows processes can shrink.